# why do I get empty by calling get_object(self._bucket_name, object_name) of Minio?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, ceph, minio

I am using S3 cluster. My SDK is Minio. My client code is:

```
_client = Minio(domain, access_key=access_key, secret_key=secret_key)
```

I can fetch the file and save to my local from S3 cluster by calling `_client.fget_object(self._bucket_name, object_name, file_path_to_save)`  successfully every time. But sometimes I can't get the file by calling my following function, the response.data is '' and response.status is 200. But sometimes, I can get the correct file content. For example, I get the correct file content when I run the code, and then I get '' as the file content when I run it again.

```
def get_file_object(self, object_name):
    try:
        response = self._client.get_object(self._bucket_name, object_name)
        # Read data from response.
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
    finally:
        print(response.status)
        response.close()
        response.release_conn()
        return response.data
```

My python version is 3.8.5, and Minio version is 7.0.2.
It is very weird. Any suggestions to me are welcome. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

All is OK after I changed the SDK from Minio to boto3. I think that should be a bug of Minio.

Comment: I ran into the same problem... in my case it was pandas dataframe. it seems that there's problem with mid size large file ( 18MB) because smaller files ( 2 or 3 mb) are downloaded correctly